# Javascript concatenation error while adding form name using smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

What's wrong in this, i want to pass the value to the field of the specific form

```
var formid = 'addtaskform{/literal}{$smarty.session.formno}{literal}';
document.formid.title.value = 'yeah';
```

i am getting this error

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with concatenation in that case. You probably do something else wrong.

Look at the following example:

PHP file:

```
$_SESSION['formno'] = 5;
$smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

Smarty template file:

```
<input type="text" id="addtaskform5" value="5" />
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
var formid = 'addtaskform{/literal}{$smarty.session.formno}{literal}';
document.getElementById(formid).value = 'yeah';
{/literal}
</script>
```

It works fine. Value of input is changed from `5` to `yeah`

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't have a form element with the id `formid` in your site, at least it is not what you actually want to achieve.

What you are looking for is this:

```
document[formid].title.value = 'yeah';
```

`document.formid` ([Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation))  : get the element with the *id* `formid`
`document[formid]` ([Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)): get the element with the *id* that is stored in the value `formid`